# Simple example of why Differential Equations can be NP Hard

Tags: differential-equations, np

Just looking for a simple example of why Differential Equations can be NP hard

Edit:

It appears that the answer below may be what I was looking for, but I am clarifying just in case:

> Slides 58--72 [here](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kawamura/slides_cambridge.pdf) show a SAT reduction.

Background:

I remember reading somewhere that improving the approximated solutions to NP hard problems would lead to better approximate numeric solutions. (e.g. weather predictions via Differential Equations)

Is this true? and if so, then in a very general sense, I am trying to understand where the "NP hardness" arises in solving Differential Equations and other numeric problem solving algorithms, if at all.

[here is a related link although it does not mention Differential Equations directly](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2013/08/p-np-and-weather.html)

Comment: Please give some background.

Comment: Give a specific decision problem, not just something as vague as "solving differential equations", and ask on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ please.

Comment: I think it's well-established precedent that questions on complexity theory are on-topic for Math Overflow, irrespective of the existence of cstheory.

Comment: Generic differential equations cannot be "solved" in any reasonable meaning of the word. So it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I've given some background plus a link

Answer (score 3):

Slides 58--72 [here](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kawamura/slides_cambridge.pdf) show a SAT reduction.